# Mercurial 2.1: how can I use pull/incoming without getting return code 1 when there are no changes?

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial 2.1, the pull and incoming commands now have return code 1 when there are no changes. So is there now an alternative command with which I can on the command line do something like the next?

```
hg pull && echo "No changes, carry on."
```

Case in point: checkoutmanager now complains that something went wrong when updating a mercurial checkout, when in reality there were simply no changes: https://bitbucket.org/reinout/checkoutmanager/issue/17

See the mercurial 2.1 release notes, that mention this for pull (but not for incoming).
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UpgradeNotes#A2.1:_phases.2C_various_minor_changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That return code change will be reverted for the next minor release.

See: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2012-February/037986.html

Comment: Ah, thanks, that is good news.  I *did* search for this problem before posting this question, but that mailing list answer did not come up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `hg incoming` and if the return code is 1 you know there's no change.

The problem with `pull` is that when it returns 1 as returncode, it means either "no changes" or "unresolved files", this is not the case with `incoming`, when you have a returncode of 1 you can safely say that there's no change.

In pseudo code, it will give something like this :

```
hg incoming
if(returncode = 0)
    hg pull
else
    echo "No changes, carry on."
```

Comment: Thanks, but a return code of 1 for incoming (or pull) can not only mean that there are no changes, but also that the upstream repository is gone or the server is on fire, or other disasters.  I don't think "No changes, carry on." is the correct message then. :-)

Comment: @maurits you can test the connectivity some place else, but you're right, the solution is far from perfect... I've done the hypothesis that "other factors" were taken care off...